# Change all values of input types with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

What I at the moment got is a problem where I wanna change each elements value where the id matches from the input type. Please look at my jsFiddle, this should clear up alot for you. The thing is that the values won't change of all the input types it only changes the first input type of that id. Tried using the .each function as well but didn't help.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="first" value="tesdafsdf" />
<input type="text" id="second" />
<input type="text" id="second" />
<input type="text" id="second" />
<input type="text" id="second" />
<input type="text" id="second" />
<input type="text" id="second" />
<input type="text" id="second" />
<input type="text" id="second" />
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#first').keyup(function() {
    updateSearch();
});

var updateSearch = function() {
    $('#second').each(function(index, value) {
        this.value = $('#first').val();
    });
};

//Change the values for testing purpose
updateSearch();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZLr9N/377/

Comment: ID of an element must be the same.. use class

Comment: @ArunPJohny Wait what that actually worked, can you further elleborate why this is? It's making no sense to me.

Comment: This has some Explanation **[Id's must be unique](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/127180)**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) is used to uniquely identify an element so **ID of an element must be unique**.

> It must be unique in a document, and is often used to retrieve the
>   element using [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById). Other common usages of id include using
>   the element's [ID as a selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors) when styling the document with [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS).

When you have to group multiple element one of the easiest way is to use class attribute.

When you use an id selector, it will return only the first element matching the ID rest of the elements will be ignored.

So

```js
$('.first').keyup(function() {
  updateSearch();
});

var updateSearch = function() {
  $('.second').val($('.first').val());
};

//Change the values for testing purpose
updateSearch();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="first" value="tesdafsdf" />
<input type="text" class="second" />
<input type="text" class="second" />
<input type="text" class="second" />
<input type="text" class="second" />
<input type="text" class="second" />
<input type="text" class="second" />
<input type="text" class="second" />
<input type="text" class="second" />
```

Comment: I wanna thank you very much for your input, this is valuable information and will really help me improving! I will accept your answer as answer in 8 minutes as I got to wait.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunatly HTML element id's need to be different, they are meant to be unique identifiers. Classes however can be applied to multiple elements like so:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="first" value="tesdafsdf" />
<input type="text" class="second" />
<input type="text" class="second" />
<input type="text" class="second" />
<input type="text" class="second" />
<input type="text" class="second" />
<input type="text" class="second" />
<input type="text" class="second" />
<input type="text" class="second" />
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#first').keyup(function() {
    updateSearch();
});

var updateSearch = function() {
    $('.second').each(function(index, value) {
        this.value = $('#first').val();
    });
};

//Change the values for testing purpose
updateSearch();
```

Comment: Why "Unfortunatly"? :P

Comment: Never knew that that even mattered in js/jquery/html, thanks for clearing this up for me!

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to set values of fields using `ID` attribute

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("[id='second']").each(function(){
      $(this).val('test');
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="first" value="tesdafsdf" />
<input type="text" id="second" />
<input type="text" id="second" />
<input type="text" id="second" />
<input type="text" id="second" />
<input type="text" id="second" />
<input type="text" id="second" />
<input type="text" id="second" />
<input type="text" id="second" />
```